# Can smart contract 'trigger' a payment between wallets?

Tags: contract-development, tokens

Imagine:

Buyer and seller agree to a smart contract on and own both a ERC20 compatible wallet. Seller fails to deliver the product so buyer get's his tokens back.

In this example the tokens where already sent to the Smart Contract before it executed (or even could execute). But is it also possible to trigger payments between wallets without having to send tokens to the Smart Contract before execution?

Obviously some problems could arise right here (e.g. buyer transferring all his tokens another wallet) but that is not the question.

Hope you guys can answer this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only if your wallet is a contract.